# Solving a wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the wave equation $$\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\partial _{tt}u - \bigtriangleup u = 0  &   in  \hspace{0.2cm} D \times  (0, + \infty ) \\ 
u = 0 & on \hspace{0.2cm} \partial D \times (0, + \infty ) \\ 
u = u_{0} & on \hspace{0.2cm} D \times (0) \\ 
\partial _{t}u = u_{1} & on \hspace{0.2cm} D \times (0).
\end{array} 
\right.$$

I search a solution of the above equation in the form $u(x,t)=v(x) \varphi (t)$

Prove that $v$ is solution of the Helmholtz equation in D, i.e. $\bigtriangleup v +  \omega ^{2}v = 0$ in D with Dirichlet data on the boundary. Deduce the behavior of $\varphi$.

I had proved the first term. But I don't understand the second term question "Deduce the behavior of $\varphi$"

Can you help me explain the question? (Deduce the behavior of $\varphi$)

Thank you.

Comment: By $\Delta$ did you mean $\nabla$?

Comment: Well if you insert what you got into the PDE you should get an ODE in time for $\varphi$, right?

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you explain more clearly? – user159517 16

Comment: No, I don't understand the question "Deduce the behavior of φ"  - polfosol

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $\Delta$ means $\nabla^2$. If you have $u(\mathbf{x}, t) = v(\mathbf{x})\phi(t)$ then

$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u(\mathbf{x}, t)  = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}v(\mathbf{x})\phi(t) = v(\mathbf{x})\frac{d^2}{d t^2}\phi(t)
$$

and

$$
\Delta u(\mathbf{x}, t) = \Delta v(\mathbf{x})\phi(t) = \phi(t) \Delta v(\mathbf{x})
$$

Taking this results we arrive to

$$
\frac{1}{\phi(t)} \frac{d^2}{d t^2}\phi(t) = \frac{1}{v(\mathbf{x})} \Delta v(\mathbf{x})
$$

On the left you have a function that depends only on $t$, and on the right you have a function that depends only on $\mathbf{x}$, this can only be true if both functions are are a constant

$$
\frac{1}{\phi(t)} \frac{d^2}{d t^2}\phi(t) = c = {\rm constant}
$$

A constant can be either, positive, zero or negative. A positive constant $c = \lambda^2$ would imply that $\phi$ will either grow or decay exponentially with time $\phi(t)\sim e^{\pm \lambda t}$. And so will do $u(\mathbf{x},t)$. Which actually violates the conservation of energy for this wave equation, again, assuming that $\Delta = \nabla^2$. A similar argument can be applied for $c = 0$.

The remaining case is $c = -\omega^2 < 0$, in this case, the solutions are

$$
\frac{1}{\phi(t)} \frac{d^2}{d t^2}\phi(t) = -\omega^2 \quad\Rightarrow\quad \phi(t) = A\cos(\omega t + \varphi)
$$

That is $\phi$ is harmonic

Comment: I got it, thank you so much